# div.dialog is not a function in Modal Popup JQuery 3.5.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

So decided to update some packages in my project and there is always issues with that. I have a setup where a link brings up a modal dialog with the `.chtml` file in it. I use a helper I call ModalDialogExtentions which calls on a Javascript file called modaldialog.js. When I updated the JQuery and Bootstrap, although I do not believe updating the bootstrap has anything to do with it, my modals show up at the bottom of the page - like stucky.

I get an error in the Console window that says `modaldialog.js:30 Uncaught TypeError: div.dialog is not a function` Which brings me to this:

```
function openModalDialog(dialogDivId, title) {
var div = $("#" + dialogDivId);
div.dialog({
    title: title,
    close: new Function("clearModalDialog('" + dialogDivId + "');"),
    modal: true,
    width: "auto",
    height: "auto",
    resizable: true 
});

setFormDataAjaxAttributes(dialogDivId);
```

}

Does anyone know what has changed in this version of JQuery? Original was version 1.10.2. I know I have updated this to 3.x.x something and it worked fine. but this version does not. It also mentions in the console about this file as well `JQuery.unobtrusive-ajax.js`. I updated this as well.

Full Console Error:

```
modaldialog.js:30 Uncaught TypeError: div.dialog is not a function
at openModalDialog (modaldialog.js:30)
at HTMLAnchorElement.eval (eval at getFunction (jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js:34), <anonymous>:3:1)
at Object.success (jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js:105)
at c (jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2)
at l (jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2)
at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2)
```

Thanks for your help!

UPDATE:

This is one of the modaldialog extentions:

```
 public static MvcHtmlString ModalDialogActionLink(this AjaxHelper ajaxHelper, string linkText, string actionName, string dialogTitle, string CssClass)
    {
        var dialogDivId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        return ajaxHelper.ActionLink(linkText, actionName, routeValues: null,
                ajaxOptions: new AjaxOptions
                {
                    UpdateTargetId = dialogDivId,
                    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                    HttpMethod = "GET",
                    OnBegin = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "prepareModalDialog('{0}')", dialogDivId),
                    OnFailure = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "clearModalDialog('{0}');alert('You are not authorized to access this area!')", dialogDivId),
                    OnSuccess = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "openModalDialog('{0}', '{1}')", dialogDivId, dialogTitle)
                }, htmlAttributes: new { @class = CssClass });

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have facing the same issue that dialog was not open ,
As i debugged things and found out the which is my Jquery library i updated my Jquery and Jquery min library from 1.8 to 3.5.1 as Jquery 3.5.1 is not supporting Jquery dialog anymore,

As some library functions are deprecated l such MISE and curCSS i resolve it through fixing these

```
jQuery.browser = {};
(function () {
    jQuery.browser.msie = false;
        jQuery.browser.msie = true;
        jQuery.browser.version = RegExp.$1;
    }
    
    jQuery.curCSS = function(element, prop, val) {
        return jQuery(element).css(prop, val);
    };
```